# Msal React TypeScript types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I am working on implementing the Msal-React authentication in my application.

I am able to get everything working properly but I am getting a type error.

```
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)
  const msal = useMsal()
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      msal.instance.handleRedirectPromise().then(() => {
        const allAccounts = msal.instance.getAllAccounts()
        console.log(allAccounts)
        if (allAccounts.length > 0) setCurrentUser(allAccounts[0])
      })
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated])
```

They error I am getting is due to not declaring the type of `currentUser` and reads.

```
Argument of type 'AccountInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'.
  Type 'AccountInfo' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: null): null'
```

So it looks like there is a type `AccountInfo` but I am not sure how to find out how that type is constructed.

Comment: `AccountInfo` is the type that `msal-react` package supports. The following link is the link for `AccountInfo`.  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/src/naa/AccountInfo.ts

Comment: Thank you! Are these type declarations importable or will I just have to copy and paste?

Comment: I think you should find the way to import AccountInfo type.

Comment: I found it. `import { AccountInfo } from "@azure/msal-browser";` please try to use it

Comment: @GreenDev how is that done. Sadly there is no documentation on this.

Comment: I didnt find the document, but found one Login sample using `AccountInfo` type. Please check this link.  https://refine.dev/docs/advanced-tutorials/auth/azure-ad/#configure-the-msalprovider-component

Answer (score 0):

You can import AccountInfo type from `msal-browser` package.

```
import { AccountInfo } from "@azure/msal-browser"
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<AccountInfo>(null);
```